# why did this error comes while running the minishift.exe file?

Tags: openshift, virtualbox, hyper-v, hypervisor, minishift

why did this error comes while running the minishift.exe file using the command (miniscript.exe start--vm-driver virtualbox) even though I disable hyper-v feature in windows features?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el8Zb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqC3K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your laptop after disabling the hyper-v? You may need to restart your laptop to refresh registry values for hyper-v and then ultimately command shell gets aware that there is no hyper-v active atm & use virtual box driver.